# Jenkins build failed because of an no value to a variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I have a Jenkins file as like below:

```
    stage("Deploy artifact for k8s sync")
    {
        sh '''
            ns_exists=`kubectl get ns | grep ${target_cluster}`
            if [ -z "$ns_exists" ]
            then
                echo "No namespace ${consider_namespace} exists in the cluster ${target_cluster}"
                echo "Creating namespace ${consider_namespace} in the cluster ${target_cluster}"
                kubectl apply "some yaml file"
            else
                if [ "${consider_kinds}" = "all" ] || [ "${consider_kinds}" = "serviceaccounts" ]
                then
                    echo "Applying source serviceaccounts on target cluster ${target_cluster}"
                    kubectl "some yaml file"
                fi

                if [ "${consider_kinds}" = "all" ] || [ "${consider_kinds}" = "secrets" ]
                then
                    echo "Applying source secrets on target cluster ${target_cluster}"
                    kubectl "some yaml file"
                fi
                
                if [ "${consider_kinds}" = "all" ] || [ "${consider_kinds}" = "configmaps" ]
                then
                    echo "Applying source configmaps on target cluster ${target_cluster}"
                    kubectl apply -f ${BUILD_NUMBER}-${source_cluster}-${consider_namespace}-configmaps.yaml
                fi
```

However, when I run, it fails with the error like below:

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy artefact for k8s sync) (hide)
[Pipeline] sh
+ kubectl get ns
+ grep test-central-eks
+ ns_exists=
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Wondering how to resolve it and why it should fail in first place?

Comment: Usually, for me, it's because of closing brackets. can you recheck this maybe?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by closing brackets? and where about to check?

Comment: I mean the braces `{}` for each block. did you get it validated before using it in pipeline though?

Comment: SO :  a negative rating should come with a meaningful justification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you have a couple of things that make this to fail.

From your pipeline extract I can see that you are using variables that are not defined in the script, so I guess those are somehow environment variables or coming from previous step. In order to be able to use it, you will need string interpolation, in your case, a triple double quote https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_double_quoted_string

```
stage("Deploy artifact for k8s sync")
    {
        sh """
```

In the other hand, grep exit code is 1 when there is not match, in case you need to continue in the case that there is not match you can put a block command with a true condition

```sh
ns_exists=`kubectl get ns | {grep ${target_cluster} || true; }`
```

Finally, a good way to catch this problems is to replay the pipeline with debug in the shell blocks by adding `set -x` at the beginning of the sh `sh` block.

Please note as well that stderr is not printed, in case you need it you would need to redirect to the stdout and readed from `returnStdout: true` option of jenkins `sh` or a custom file where the stdout is redirected